# How to apply custom zoom to UIImagePicker camera?

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an custom camera control having slider to apply zoom. I am able to zoom image with following code:

```
self.pickerReference.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, zoom, zoom);
```

But when i get image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I get original image for `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`, not the zoomed one. And for `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` there is no image.

I have also tried:

```
currentImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:currentImage];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(v.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, zoom, zoom);
[v drawRect:pickerReference.view.bounds];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
zoomedCurImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// Write image to PNG file
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(zoomedCurImg, 0.4) writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];
```

This does apply zoom to original image but zoom is applied always at top left corner & not to where it is to be applied.

Please suggest solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you got any final solution? Please share..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a different piece of code and turning off auto layout fixed it for me.  Not sure if that applies here but it's worth a shot.